# Pass through list by period

Tags: c#, list, generics, collections

I have a `List<Items>` for example 365 elements

```
    public DateTime DayD { get; set; }
    public double Day { get; set; }
    public double Week { get; set; }
    public double Month { get; set; }
```

How to pass through the list by period 30 day - mean for each element select next 30 element.

Comment: Do you mean List<List<Items>> ? Where inner list contains List of 30 element.

Comment: Mean List<Items> => List<Items(first 30)> => List<Items(second 30)>  etc... 9/25/2014 to 9/25/2015 first group would be a 9/25/2014 - 10/25/2014 next 9/26/2014/ - 10/26/2014 and up to end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use LINQ with a `yield return`, something like :

```
static IEnumerable<List<Item>> GetXMany(int pageSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i+=pageSize)
    {
        yield return items.Skip(i).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
}
```

and loop through it with :

```
foreach (List<Item> items in GetXMany(30))
{

}
```